# Can I use a USB dongle as a WiFi hotspot?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a desktop without wireless network card running Windows 7 and a Wifi dongle Reliance Netconnect.

My PC has an internet connection through ethernet. I want to use dongle as Wifi hotspot so that I can use internet on my Android phone. Is it possible? If so then how?

Answer (score 1):

While I believe this to be a duplicate of a large number of questions, I couldn't find a single one with a satisfactory answer.

So I'll quote from [this article](http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/3849841/How-to-Create-Wireless-Hosted-Networks-in-Windows-7.htm):

> Manually create a virtual AP with netsh
>
> If you want to experiment with the wireless Hosted Network feature
>   with text commands, click the Start button, enter “cmd” and hit Enter.
>   Once the Command Prompt window appears, you can enter the following to
>   set the network details:
>
> ```
> netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=YourVirtualNetworkName key=YourNetworkPassword
> ```
>
> Of course, replace the SSID and key placeholders with your desired
>   network name and WPA2-PSK encryption key.
>
> Before you enable the Hosted Network, you can configure the real
>   network adapter to share its Internet access using the Internet
>   Connection Sharing (ICS) feature of Windows. This way people
>   connecting to the virtual AP will receive Internet access. You can
>   leave the Command Prompt open so you can start the Hosted Network
>   later.
>
> To enable ICS, navigate through the Control Panel or Network and
>   Sharing Center to bring up the Network Connections window. Then
>   right-click the network adapter that’s connected to the Internet and
>   select Properties. Then select the Sharing tab, check the Allow other
>   network users to connect through this computer’s Internet connection,
>   choose the Hosted Network Connection from the drop-down listbox, and
>   click OK.
>
> Now return to the Command Prompt and enter the following to enable the
>   Hosted Network:
>
> ```
> netsh wlan start hostednetwork
> ```
>
> To manually turn the Hosted Network off, enter the following:
>
> ```
> netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
> ```
>
> To see the Hosted Network details (see Figure 3), including the MAC
>   addresses of connected users, enter the following:
>
> ```
> netsh wlan show hostednetwork
> ```
>
> To change the WPA2-PSK key, you can enter the following:
>
> ```
> netsh wlan refresh hostednetwork YourNewNetworkPassword
> ```
>
> Now others nearby should see the Hosted Network appear in their list
>   of available wireless networks. They can connect like normal and enter
>   the encryption key when prompted.
>
> Remember, you’ll have to manually start the Hosted Network again, if
>   desired, after rebooting the computer. Most importantly, remember
>   sharing isn’t blocked; make sure you only invite people you trust.

If I remember correctly, this doesn't work with some older WiFi chipsets, so it might depend on the chipset in the WiFi dongle. There should be no difference between a USB WiFi card (external) and a PCI WiFi card (internal).